# Load C# (COM) in a Credential Provider : working with winlogon, but problem when explorer loads it

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, credential-providers

I created a custom Credential Provider for Windows.
The base DLL is in C++ and it loads a C# DLL trought a COM interface.

```
    if (CoInitialize(NULL) != S_OK) {


        hr = _authenticationManager.CreateInstance("{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}");

        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << std::hex << (int)hr;
        MessageBoxA(NULL, stream.str().c_str(), "", 0);
```

The class is registered like that :

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record\{71C93A0D-861E-3195-A2D8-51DA34307BCA}\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="AuthenticationManager.BUTTON_TYPE"
"Assembly"="AuthenticationManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager]
@="AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager\CLSID]
@="{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}]
@="AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager"
"Assembly"="AuthenticationManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager"
"Assembly"="AuthenticationManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}\ProgId]
@="AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManager"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
```

The C# DLL delcaration looks like this :

```
[Guid("BAF984BD-0D41-42D1-AA49-4BC98EE6C4A1")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IAuthenticationManager))]
public class AuthenticationManager : IAuthenticationManager
```

**It works perfectly when using winlogon to log to the computer, when i log off, the provider loads, and the C# too, all is good**

But, when i use it for an other purpose, it fails to load the COM component : CreateInstance returns 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG).

Example of usage that does not works : SHIFT+RIGHT CLICK on a exe -> Execute as other user
The provider is loaded, and the class is not found...

I heard on forums that 32 and 64 bits mixing can be the source of the problem, but both process (winlogon & explorer) are x64, and all my dlls (credential + authenticationManager) are x64 too.

Can you please help me, i have been stuck for 3 days....

Thank you very much.

Comment: You probably want to look at https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anymore, COM is a bad idea! Alternativelly, you can use Visual C++ CLI. CLI support is a bridge between native C++ and managed C#.NET libraries.

Comment: Can i compile my credential provider in C++ CLI, and get it loaded by windows ?

Comment: I tested and i cant even compile it because it needs secur32 that is not available with CLI.

Comment: That not what i wanted to do. I wanted to make work my COM avoiding this C++CLI. But finally...... i backed up on this solution.